# Сохранение/чтение таблицы Lua в/из файла

Tags: lua

Как грамотно реализовать сохранение таблицы Lua в файл и как прочитать данные из файла обратно в таблицу.
Супер универсальность не нужна и лучше без внешних зависимостей (буду вставлять в LuaLaTeX). Подойдет пример под мою таблицу из примера `tquest` .

Пробовал разные примеры, например, это: http://lua-users.org/wiki/SaveTableToFile .

Не работает. В файле 5 записей, а у меня их 4! Возможно я что-то не так сделал.

```
return {
-- Table: {1}
{
   {2},
   {3},
   {4},
   {5},
},
-- Table: {2}
{
   "{=1}~Коммутативность",
   "{=2}~Ассоциативность бинарных операций",
   "{=3}~Идемпотентность унарных операций",
   "{=4}~Дистрибутивность бинарных операций между бинарными",
   "{=5}~Факторизация унарных операций",
   ["q"]="Какое из свойств \\textbf{реляционной алгебры} представлено далее?\\par \\begin{equation*} \\begin{aligned}U(U(R, S), T) &\\rightarrow U(R, U(S, T)) \\\\ CP(CP(R, S), T) &\\rightarrow CP(R, CP(S, T)) \\\\ J_{F_2}(J_{F_1}(R, S), T)&\\rightarrow J_{F_1}(R, J_{F_2}(S, T)) \\end{aligned} \\end{equation*}",
   ["a"]=2,
},
-- Table: {3}
{
   "{=1}~Свойство стилевого оформления и его значение",
   "{=2}~Пространство имен",
   "{=3}~Префикс пространства имен",
   "{=4}~Название атрибута и его значение",
   ["q"]="Что должно быть на изображении ниже за знаками вопроса?\\par\\begin{center} \\includegraphics[width=0.7\\linewidth]{xml_v_bd_test_fig_1.pdf}\\end{center}",
   ["a"]=4,
},
-- Table: {4}
{
   "{=1}~Процедура \\textbf{БД}, автоматически вызываемая \\textbf{SQL}~-- сервером при обновлении, удалении или добавлении новой записи в таблицах \\textbf{БД}",
   "{=2}~Процедура \\textbf{БД}, вручную вызываемая \\textbf{SQL}~-- сервером при обновлении, удалении или добавлении новой записи в таблицах \\textbf{БД}",
   "{=3}~Модуль, написанный на любом языке, который выполняет групповое изменение данных в \\textbf{БД}",
   "{=4}~Модуль, написанный на процедурном языке и хранящийся в \\textbf{БД} как метаданные, который можно вызывать из программы",
   ["q"]="Триггер это \\ldots~?",
   ["a"]=1,
},
-- Table: {5}
{
   "{=1}~xmlns",
   "{=2}~xhtml",
   "{=3}~xmlds",
   "{=4}~xslns",
   ["q"]="С помощью какого тега в \\textbf{XML} объявляют пространства имен?",
   ["a"]=1,
},
}
```

Мой пример:

```
local function createtbl()
    tbl=tbl or {}
    table.insert(tbl, {q="Какое из свойств \\textbf{реляционной алгебры} представлено далее?\\par \\begin{equation*} \\begin{aligned}U(U(R, S), T) &\\rightarrow U(R, U(S, T)) \\\\ CP(CP(R, S), T) &\\rightarrow CP(R, CP(S, T)) \\\\ J_{F_2}(J_{F_1}(R, S), T)&\\rightarrow J_{F_1}(R, J_{F_2}(S, T)) \\end{aligned} \\end{equation*}",
    a=2,
    [1]="{=1}~Коммутативность",
    [2]="{=2}~Ассоциативность бинарных операций",
    [3]="{=3}~Идемпотентность унарных операций",
    [4]="{=4}~Дистрибутивность бинарных операций между бинарными",
    [5]="{=5}~Факторизация унарных операций"
    })

    table.insert(tbl, {q="Что должно быть на изображении ниже за знаками вопроса?\\par\\begin{center} \\includegraphics[width=0.7\\linewidth]{xml_v_bd_test_fig_1.pdf}\\end{center}",
    a=4,
    [1]="{=1}~Свойство стилевого оформления и его значение",
    [2]="{=2}~Пространство имен",
    [3]="{=3}~Префикс пространства имен",
    [4]="{=4}~Название атрибута и его значение"
    })

    table.insert(tbl, {q="Триггер это \\ldots~?",
    a=1,
    [1]="{=1}~Процедура \\textbf{БД}, автоматически вызываемая \\textbf{SQL}~-- сервером при обновлении, удалении или добавлении новой записи в таблицах \\textbf{БД}",
    [2]="{=2}~Процедура \\textbf{БД}, вручную вызываемая \\textbf{SQL}~-- сервером при обновлении, удалении или добавлении новой записи в таблицах \\textbf{БД}",
    [3]="{=3}~Модуль, написанный на любом языке, который выполняет групповое изменение данных в \\textbf{БД}",
    [4]="{=4}~Модуль, написанный на процедурном языке и хранящийся в \\textbf{БД} как метаданные, который можно вызывать из программы"
    })

    table.insert(tbl, {q="С помощью какого тега в \\textbf{XML} объявляют пространства имен?",
    a=1,
    [1]="{=1}~xmlns",
    [2]="{=2}~xhtml",
    [3]="{=3}~xmlds",
    [4]="{=4}~xslns"
    })
    return tbl
end

-- функция печати таблицы
local function printall(arr)
    local ans = "["
    for i,n in ipairs(tbl) do
        ans = ans .. n.a .. ","
        print("[" .. i .. "] " .. n.q .. "\n")
        for j = 1, #n do
            local s = "    [" .. j .. "] " .. n[j]
            print(s)
        end
        print("\n")
    end
    ans = ans:sub(1, ans:len()-1) .. "]"
    print("answer" .. ans)
end


print ("create table with questions");

local tquest = createtbl();

print ("\n" .. "######################################################");

printall(tquest);

print ("######################################################" .. "\n");

--print ("save table into file");

--table.save(tquest, "tquest.txt");

--print ("load table from file");

--local t2,err = table.load( "tquest.txt" );

--print ("print table t2");

--print ("\n" .. "######################################################");

--printall(t2);

--print ("######################################################" .. "\n");
```

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: `-- Table: {1}` что-то не видно при создании

Comment: Именно так. Я в вопросе это написал. Все говорят про универсальные методы сохранения/чтения в/из файла, но у меня они не работают. @Mike V.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/dpino/af37d70554d157bbee289f489945cce5 - Это вариант сохраняет в файл, но как прочитать из файла в таблицу? @Mike V.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ну вот так примерно будет работать:

```
local function createtbl()
    local tbl = {}
    table.insert(tbl, {q="Какое из свойств \\textbf{реляционной алгебры} представлено далее?\\par \\begin{equation*} \\begin{aligned}U(U(R, S), T) &\\rightarrow U(R, U(S, T)) \\\\ CP(CP(R, S), T) &\\rightarrow CP(R, CP(S, T)) \\\\ J_{F_2}(J_{F_1}(R, S), T)&\\rightarrow J_{F_1}(R, J_{F_2}(S, T)) \\end{aligned} \\end{equation*}",
    a=2,
    [1]="{=1}~Коммутативность",
    [2]="{=2}~Ассоциативность бинарных операций",
    [3]="{=3}~Идемпотентность унарных операций",
    [4]="{=4}~Дистрибутивность бинарных операций между бинарными",
    [5]="{=5}~Факторизация унарных операций"
    })

    table.insert(tbl, {q="Что должно быть на изображении ниже за знаками вопроса?\\par\\begin{center} \\includegraphics[width=0.7\\linewidth]{xml_v_bd_test_fig_1.pdf}\\end{center}",
    a=4,
    [1]="{=1}~Свойство стилевого оформления и его значение",
    [2]="{=2}~Пространство имен",
    [3]="{=3}~Префикс пространства имен",
    [4]="{=4}~Название атрибута и его значение"
    })

    table.insert(tbl, {q="Триггер это \\ldots~?",
    a=1,
    [1]="{=1}~Процедура \\textbf{БД}, автоматически вызываемая \\textbf{SQL}~-- сервером при обновлении, удалении или добавлении новой записи в таблицах \\textbf{БД}",
    [2]="{=2}~Процедура \\textbf{БД}, вручную вызываемая \\textbf{SQL}~-- сервером при обновлении, удалении или добавлении новой записи в таблицах \\textbf{БД}",
    [3]="{=3}~Модуль, написанный на любом языке, который выполняет групповое изменение данных в \\textbf{БД}",
    [4]="{=4}~Модуль, написанный на процедурном языке и хранящийся в \\textbf{БД} как метаданные, который можно вызывать из программы"
    })

    table.insert(tbl, {q="С помощью какого тега в \\textbf{XML} объявляют пространства имен?",
    a=1,
    [1]="{=1}~xmlns",
    [2]="{=2}~xhtml",
    [3]="{=3}~xmlds",
    [4]="{=4}~xslns"
    })
    return tbl
end

-- функция печати таблицы
local function printall(arr)
    local ans = "["
    for i,n in ipairs(arr) do -- ? тут была tbl 
        ans = ans .. n.a .. ","
        print("[" .. i .. "] " .. n.q .. "\n")
        for j = 1, #n do
            local s = "    [" .. j .. "] " .. n[j]
            print(s)
        end
        print("\n")
    end
    ans = ans:sub(1, ans:len()-1) .. "]"
    print("answer" .. ans)
end


print ("== 1 ==");

local tquest = createtbl();

--=========== 
    local function TableToText(tt, level)
       level = (level or 0) + 1 
       local rep = string.rep("\t",level)
       if type(tt) == 'table' then
          local s = '\n' .. rep .. '{ \n'
          for k,v in pairs(tt) do
             if type(k) ~= 'number' then k = '"'..k..'"' end
             local tmp = TableToText(v, level) 
             if type(v) == 'string' then tmp = '"' .. tmp .. '"' end
             s = s ..  rep .. '['..k..'] = ' .. tmp .. ',\n'
          end
          return s .. rep ..'}'
       else
          return tostring(tt)
       end
    end

    local filename = 'D:\\lua_data.lua'
    local h = io.open (filename , "w+b")
    if h==nil then print("error file create") return end
    local str = TableToText(tquest) 
    str = "return " .. str  .. '\n'
    h:write( str)
    h:close()
--===========
print ("== 2 ==");

local table_restored = dofile(filename)

print ("== 3 ==");

printall(table_restored)
```

Comment: Спасибо что нашли ошибку в функции printall(arr)! Ваше решение почти работает. Есть какие-то проблем с двойной косой чертой "\\". Вот как выглядит часть первой строки в файле: " \textbf{реляционной алгебры} представлено далее?\par \begin{equation*} \begin{aligned}U(U(R, S), T) &\rightarrow U(R, U(S, T)) \\ " Из-за особенностей черта всегда удваивается. В файле удвоение исчезает. Вместо "\\" сохраняет "\", вместо "\\\\" - "\\".  Функция TableToText - рекурсивная (круто)!!! Как решить проблему с двойной косой чертой. Спасибо за помощь. @Mike V.

Comment: перед записью в файл сделать подмену: `str = "return " .. str:gsub("\\","\\\\")  .. '\n'`

Comment: Большое спасибо. Остался один вопрос: куда пропадают символы "\"? В неработающих примерах так же пропадали в файлах.

Comment: в lua обратный слеш является спецсимволом для эскейпинга других спецсимволов , как % для [magic characters](https://www.lua.org/pil/20.2.html) ..чаще всего для использования кавычек внутри кавычек и самого себя .. `"Hellp \"world\""` ну или `d:\\temp.txt`

Comment: Понял. Спасибо @Mike V.

Comment: Файл сохраняется в кодировке win-1251. Можно как-то сохранять его в UTF-8? @Mike V.

Comment: Перевести текст из 1251 в UTF8 можно вызовом функции win_to_utf8 из [этого](https://gist.github.com/Egor-Skriptunoff/44a88f64f9a497919db4ad8c28259a8f) Lua-модуля

Comment: Спасибо @ESkri .